# How to chroot Arch from a Gentoo live cd?

Tags: arch-linux, gentoo, livecd, chroot

I have a laptop with 2 OS partitions: 1 for Windows 10, 1 for Arch Linux. The bootloader is the Windows one, so I cannot start Arch. Now my Windows suddenly broke, so my laptop cannot startup normally anymore.
I also have a Gentoo Live CD. Not Arch.
There are no computers near capable of burning disks (to create an Arch CD), aside from my laptop (which needs to be supplied the Gentoo disk to start-up, and that disk isn't rewritable).

How do I chroot into my Arch Linux installation utilizing only this Gentoo Live CD?

Comment: @Seth To fix the bootloader, he needs to chroot, so he can run `grub-install` or whatever.

Comment: Two observations: you don't need a CD to boot - you can boot from a USB drive instead; also, see if you you can get get `boot-repair` for Gentoo - it makes the process of grub recovery incredibly simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That’s really easy. The [arch-chroot](https://github.com/falconindy/arch-install-scripts/blob/master/arch-chroot.in) script does [the following](https://github.com/falconindy/arch-install-scripts/blob/master/common):

```
chroot_setup() {
  CHROOT_ACTIVE_MOUNTS=()
  [[ $(trap -p EXIT) ]] && die '(BUG): attempting to overwrite existing EXIT trap'
  trap 'chroot_teardown' EXIT

  chroot_maybe_add_mount "! mountpoint -q '$1'" "$1" "$1" --bind &&
  chroot_add_mount proc "$1/proc" -t proc -o nosuid,noexec,nodev &&
  chroot_add_mount sys "$1/sys" -t sysfs -o nosuid,noexec,nodev,ro &&
  ignore_error chroot_maybe_add_mount "[[ -d '$1/sys/firmware/efi/efivars' ]]" \
      efivarfs "$1/sys/firmware/efi/efivars" -t efivarfs -o nosuid,noexec,nodev &&
  chroot_add_mount udev "$1/dev" -t devtmpfs -o mode=0755,nosuid &&
  chroot_add_mount devpts "$1/dev/pts" -t devpts -o mode=0620,gid=5,nosuid,noexec &&
  chroot_add_mount shm "$1/dev/shm" -t tmpfs -o mode=1777,nosuid,nodev &&
  chroot_add_mount run "$1/run" -t tmpfs -o nosuid,nodev,mode=0755 &&
  chroot_add_mount tmp "$1/tmp" -t tmpfs -o mode=1777,strictatime,nodev,nosuid
}
```

... and then copies over `resolv.conf`.

So you need to:

```
mount proc "$chroot_directory/proc" -t proc -o nosuid,noexec,nodev
mount sys "$chroot_directory/sys" -t sysfs -o nosuid,noexec,nodev,ro
mount udev "$chroot_directory/dev" -t devtmpfs -o mode=0755,nosuid
mount devpts "$chroot_directory/dev/pts" -t devpts -o mode=0620,gid=5,nosuid,noexec
mount shm "$chroot_directory/dev/shm" -t tmpfs -o mode=1777,nosuid,nodev
mount run "$chroot_directory/run" -t tmpfs -o nosuid,nodev,mode=0755
mount tmp "$chroot_directory/tmp" -t tmpfs -o mode=1777,strictatime,nodev,nosuid
```

Plus, if you’re EFI-booted:

```
mount efivarfs "$chroot_directory/sys/firmware/efi/efivars" -t efivarfs -o nosuid,noexec,nodev
```

Also copy over `/etc/resolv.conf` if needed or you won’t be able to resolve DNS names.

Alternatively, you can also follow the [Gentoo chroot procedure](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Installation/Base#Chrooting):

```
mount -t proc proc "$chroot_directory/proc"
mount --rbind /sys "$chroot_directory/sys"
mount --make-rslave "$chroot_directory/sys"
mount --rbind /dev "$chroot_directory/dev"
mount --make-rslave "$chroot_directory/dev"
```

After that, just run `chroot "$chroot_directory"` or perhaps `chroot "$chroot_directory" /usr/bin/bash` if your current shell isn’t available inside the directory you’re entering.

Comment: When running either of the options you supplied, the chroot command returns `chroot: failed to run command '/bin/bash': No such file or directory`, even when supplying `/bin/bash` as an argument for chroot.

Comment: Ah, yeah. It may be located at /usr/bin/bash. I'll check and update the answer.

Comment: `/bin/bash` does exist on the live cd.

Comment: It has to exist in the chroot directory, like I wrote. It’s entering the directory and then executing the file relative to that directory.

Comment: On my Arch system, the file exists in both locations, hard-linked.

Comment: I am not smart, I forgot to actually mount the partition in the first place xd